# Strange colors in Mapquest Open Aerial tiles

Tags: colors, mapquest

I have previously used Mapquest Open Arial tiles without any trouble. However, after the last server change I get tiles with weird colors. Their example tile still looks fine:

http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/15/5240/12661.jpg

But, the ones I'm trying to download look like this:

http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/13/1927/3385.jpg

The most striking problem is that the vegetation is red.

Does anyone know what's causing this or perhaps how I can correct the colors (I have tried playing around with them a bit in gimp but I couldn't find a solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at MapQuest.  Unfortunately there was bad data in the last round of open aerial imagery updates that caused some areas (we've noticed Texas) to be seeded with discoloration from zoom level 12 and up. We've got this on our backlog, but I don't have an estimate as to when this issue will be resolved.  Thanks for your interest in our Open Tiles!